# Asana tag API query often misses newly created Tags

Tags: asana

when we create projects via API the newly created project is immediately returned in both the webApp and in the API.

But a tag created using API "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tags" is often returned only after two or three GET requests. Also in the webApp it needs a refresh, online application sync does not update new tags like Projects.

This late returns really affects the user interaction. I follow the same workflow thats used for creating and adding project, but tags feels a bit laggy. Am I missing anything?

Comment: In my tests... the newly created tag is not in the get request for tags when it isn't associated with a task.  Once associated with a task it seems to appear in the response.  However, once removed from a task it disappears from response.  @asana... seems like a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that tags which aren't associated with any tasks are - unfortunately - hidden in the app, and consequently also in the API. As you discovered, you can get the ID back from the POST to create and then associate it with a task from there (since there's little purpose in creating a tag if you're not associating it with something that shouldn't typically be a problem, but it is clunky). We are looking at changing our data model for tags to be a bit more intuitive in future, but that's still a ways off, so this is the reality for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

the newly created tag is missed in the GET /tags API from time to time. But the http response returned after creation of the new tag by POST /tags, will contain the id, name and other properties of the newly created tag. So we can add the new tag from this response.

```
 POST->  https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tags \
-u "name=fluffy" \
-u "workspace=14916"


# Response
HTTP/1.1 201
{
"data": {
"id": 1771,
"name": "fluffy",
...
}
}
```