# New tags using POST in /tags asana API endpoint does'nt create the new tag

Tags: asana

we constructed the new tag JSON like

```
data:{
    name:"busy Tag"
    notes:"This is new tag to b created in API"
    workspace:"xyz456987"
    }
```

on post http request to /tags api we get the response

```
data =     {
            color = "<null>";
            "created_at" = "2014-07-19T12:59:13.162Z";
            followers =         (
            );
            id = 14895043902988;
            name = "busy tag";
            notes = "This is new tag to b created in API";
            workspace = {
            id = 6486925687953;
            name = t;
        };
};
```

Yet the created tag doesn't appear in the web app tags list and also the api call doesn't retrieve the newly created tag.

**UPDATE:**
*when i put id of the new tag in the address bar like*

`https://app.asana.com/0/14896850962516/14896850962516`

shows the tag in the webapp. Yet the api call is unable retrieve the the newly created tag item.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asana tag API query often misses newly created Tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326969/asana-tag-api-query-often-misses-newly-created-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll quote my answer from [Asana tag API query often misses newly created Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24873988/254896):

> The answer is that tags which aren't associated with any tasks are - unfortunately - hidden in the app, and consequently also in the API. As you discovered, you can get the ID back from the POST to create and then associate it with a task from there (since there's little purpose in creating a tag if you're not associating it with something that shouldn't typically be a problem, but it is clunky). We are looking at changing our data model for tags to be a bit more intuitive in future, but that's still a ways off, so this is the reality for the foreseeable future.

Comment: right. last time I followed this workflow and it worked, 1.create new tag 2. immediately associate it to a task 3. the new tag appeared in the web app.  now i missed the step 2, and that caused the confusion. Now got it working fine. Thank you.