# Unable to add tags to workspace via Asana API

Tags: api, tags, asana

I am using the following command to add tags via the Asana API.

```
curl -u '<api_key>' https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tags -d "name=testing" -d "workspace=15601112094251"
```

I even get a successful JSON reply with the created tag object. However, I never actually see the tag inside Asana. I also do not see the tag when listing all tags for my workspace.

When I query for the tags specifically by ID, I do see it though.

Bug on Asana's side? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24873988/254896 - because of the way the data model works, tags that aren't assigned to anything are hidden.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I did not see this post when I searched.