# Asana - create tag API - can't find created tag

Tags: asana, asana-api

When I am creating a tag using API - Getting a - 201 Create - as expected

Create Request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer <my-token>" -d 'name=tag1&workspace=42783899288073' "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tags"
```

Response:

> {   "data": {
>       "id": 156692684103314,
>       "created_at": "2016-07-18T19:39:38.131Z",
>       "name": "tag1",
>       "notes": "",
>       "workspace": {
>         "id": 42783899288073,
>         "name": "Personel"
>       },
>       "color": null,
>       "followers": []   } }

When getting list of tags in a workspace - above created tag does not appear in it

Request:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer <my-token>" https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/42783899288073/tags
```

Response:

> {   "data": [
>       {
>         "id": 42788763054709,
>         "name": "Urgent"
>       },
>       {
>         "id": 155447666873671,
>         "name": "P1"
>       },
>       {
>         "id": 154977993344918,
>         "name": "Continuous"
>       },
>       {
>         "id": 155447666873680,
>         "name": "brush"
>       },
>       {
>         "id": 155447666873678,
>         "name": "study"
>       },
>       {
>         "id": 155616413301854,
>         "name": "start"
>       }   ] }

What am I missing in Create tag API?

EDIT - As @agnoster pointed out - unless there is task for that tag - it does not appear in tag list api. Create a task with this tag-id. (this task can be deleted sub-sequently). After this tag will start appearing in tag list.

Answer (score 1):

I work at Asana. It looks like I am experiencing the same issue when I try something similar. We'll take a look at this.

For now, if you add the tag you created to a task it should show up in the list. Also you can query for your tag directly using the id you get back. I think the current behavior is a bit wonky so it definitely warrants some investigation. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Thanks for the update. My use case here - let user create tags on the fly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24873988/254896 where I answered this previously

Comment: @agnoster - you are right about this. Unless there is task for that tag - it does not appear in tag list api.